# Passing a reference to an instance method in Java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a class which has several methods returning the same type. So, for example, I have the following object definition:

```
interface MyClass {
  String first();
  String second();
}
```

Then I have a method, which accepts a list of objects of this class, and should call either `first()` or `second()` method depending on the parameter. An example:

```
void myMethod(List<MyClass> objs, boolean executeFirst) {
    objs.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(executeFirst ? obj.first() : obj.second()));
}
```

Is there any way of replacing the `executeFirst` parameter with a reference to and instance method, which I want to execute on the `objs` object? So, for example, ideally I'd like to have something like this:

```
void myMethod(List<MyClass> objs, Supplier<String> instanceMethod) {
    objs.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj::instanceMethod.get());
}
```

Comment: what about using java reflection

Comment: you've defined an interface not a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `Function<MyClass, String>`, not a Supplier:

```
public void foo() {
    myMethod(someList, MyClass::first);
}

void myMethod(List<MyClass> objs, Function<MyClass, String> instanceMethod) {
    objs.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(instanceMethod.apply(obj));
}
```

Comment: FGITW! I was just about to post `objs.stream().map(instanceMethod).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: That's good too. forEachOrdered() would be more correct, though.

Comment: Sure, but I can sleep at night expecting the `List` impl to process its stream in order.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned there will me many methods in your class and you need to call them based on some flag.

Therefore you need to maintain this meta info somewhere, ideally a map.

```
Map<String, Function<MyClass, String>> meta = new HashMap<>()
```

You can either pass this meta to the method or have it as a part of the class.

I have passed it to the method,  but I hope you get the idea.

```
void myMethod(List<MyClass> objs, meta, Supplier<String> flag) {
    objs.stream().forEach(obj -> meta.get(flag.get()).apply(obj));
}
```